# Need to throw exception while joining with two table when there is no data in one table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose two tables `test1` and `test2` on which I select values from both tables using a join.

My requirement is this: when I join the two tables, if `test1` has data in it but no corresponding data is found in `test2`, then the query should throw exception.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [RAISEERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Do  left join and select where the right side is null. If the count > 0 throw the exception.

```
DECLARE @count INT

SELECT 
   @count = COUNT(*)
FROM
  test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2 
  ON t1.t1_join_col = t2.t2_join_col
WHERE 
  t2.t2_join_col IS NULL -- find where we have test1 data but not test2 data

-- Check if I need to raise an error
IF @count <> 0 
    RAISERROR (N'<<%7.3s>>', -- Message text.
           10, -- Severity,
           1, -- State,
           N'abcde'); -- First argument supplies the string.
    -- The message text returned is: <<    abc>>.
```

if you need to return the results where don't match, then add the following ELSE

```
ELSE

SELECT 
  ... cols you want
FROM
  test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2 
  ON t1.t1_join_col = t2.t2_join_col
```

You could always, put the results into a temp table and count off that, and then return off that too if you prefer to do the query only once.